# How do I change :hover status on an element when a different element is hovered over?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

```
<img>
<button>

button:hover
  color: blue
```

I want the button's :hover effect to happen when the img is hovered over. Can this be done in CSS? If not, what's the simplest way in JS (jQuery is fine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this elements have same parent, you can use "+" or "~" CSS selector

```
img:hover + button{color:red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K4U9p/

Comment: Assuming `button` follows the `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements don't have the same parent, you could use, in jQuery:

```
$img.hover(function() { //mouse enter
    $button.addClass('hover');
}, function() { //mouse leave
    $button.removeClass('hover');
});
```

To remove the event handler:

```
$img.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use (pure) JS

```
var button  = document.getElementById("button");
var img     = document.getElementById("img");

img.onmouseover = modifyButton;
img.onmouseout  = resetButton;

function modifyButton() {
    button.style.color = "red";
}

function resetButton() {
    button.style.color = "";
}
```

or you could use a single function

```
img.onmouseout = modifyButton;

function modifyButton() {
    if (button.style.color != "red") {
        button.style.color = "red"
    } else {
        button.style.color = "";
    }
}
```

Fiddles: [Two func.](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/L27VQ/)  [Single Func.](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/L27VQ/1/)